# Redux/Toolkits, useSelector Doesn't Work, Why?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

> I want to save my data in localstorage to evade the loss of it when reloading the page but i also need it in my gloable state to show a preview of it once it's added and never be lost when reloading the page,This is my slice format:

```
    import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const resumeSlicer = createSlice({
  name: "resume",
  initialState: {
    Education: [
      {
        key: NaN,
        Title: "",
        Date: "",
        Establishment: "",
        Place: "",
      },
    ],
  },
  reducers: {
    SaveEducation: (state, action) => {
      let Education = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Education"));
      if (!Education) {
        Education.push(action.payload);
        localStorage.setItem("Education", JSON.stringify(Education));
        state.Education = Education;
      } else {
        Education.push(action.payload);
        let i = 0;
        Education.map((e) => {
          e.key = i;
          i++;
          return e.key;
        });
        localStorage.setItem("Education", JSON.stringify(Education));
        state.Education = Education;
      }
    },
    getEducation: (state, action) => {
      const items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("Education"));

      const empty_array = [
        {
          key: NaN,
          Title: "",
          Date: "",
          Establishment: "",
          Place: "",
        },
      ];

      state.Education.splice(0, state.Education.length);

      state.Education = items;
    },
  },
});
```

> And this is how i fetched:

```
const EdList = useSelector((state) => state.Education);
```

> When i console.log it the result is "undefined"

> Image Preview
> https://i.stack.imgur.com/hD8bx.png

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a [minimal, complete, and reproducible code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). What we can't see it the slice/reducer, how your state reducers are combined (*if there are more*), and the complete state shape from the screenshot. You mention fetching something, is it possible whatever was fetched wasn't reduced into state correctly? For example, in the screenshot the key looks like the letter `l`.

Comment: what is the statement of `console.log(WHAT)`? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hazarding a guess that the issue is a missing reference into the state. The chunk of state will typically nest under the name you give the slice, `"resume"` in this case. This occurs when you combine the slice reducers when creating the state object for the store.

Try:

```
const EdList = useSelector((state) => state.resume.Education);
```

If it turns out this isn't the case then we'll need to see how you create/configure the store and how you combine your reducers.